# What is the best way to fill a lot of dispensers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Using mods or tools (like MCEdit filters), what is the best way to fill a substantial amount of dispensers (on the order of hundreds at once) fully with items?

Comment: not including shift click?

Comment: shift click? (I'm probably missing something super obvious)

Comment: if you shift click something in you inventory it will go into the dispensor, or chest for that matter. unless i am remembering incorrectly gonna check quick

Comment: Yah shift+left click and item in your inventory while opening the dispensor and it should go into it automatically

Comment: if thats what your looking for ill make it an answer.

Comment: Not only dispensers & chests, but shift clicking coal and a material for smelting also works (and puts them in the right spots regardless of order)

Comment: Ah no as the question says a substantial amount of dispensers. Say hundred at a time to capacity. Ideally in an automated fashion.

Comment: Why not make one and copy/paste them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MCEdit's copy & paste tool copies tile entities (like dispenser or chest inventories, furnace items, spawner settings and so on) along with the tiles. It can't (as of current pre-release of version **0.1.6**) however create fully functioning or filled dispensers by itself. The workaround is then:

1. Create the dispenser in-game and fill it up (easiest in creative mode)
2. Save and exit the game
3. Load up the world in MCEdit, select the dispenser and use the clone tool (third from left on the toolbar) to multiply it.
4. Save the world again and load it up in the game to wire up your dispensers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do copy/paste or stack with Worldedit if you are ready to install bukkit. There you fill one, then select it and type //stack 50. It will then create a row of 50 dispensers that are identical. You can do that with 4 above each other, and you have 200 in one go etc.

Comment: WorldEdit is also included in SinglePlayerCommands.